# How to get the title of anchor tag which is inside a list and having class as selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unstructured list(`ul`) inside `div` tags and I am trying to get the title of an anchor tag, which is inside an `li` that has `class="selected"`.

```
<div class="mainmenu">
    <div class="mainmenulinks">
        <ul>
            <li class="selected">
                <a class="topmenu-navigation-links" id="topMenuItem0" href="" title="Private">
                    <span class="span-link-Private">Private</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="topmenu-navigation-links" id="topMenuItem1" href="" title="Business">
                    <span class="span-link-Business">Business</span>
                </a>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a class="topmenu-navigation-links" id="topMenuItem2" href="" title="Broker">
                    <span class="span-link-Broker">Broker</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, I should be getting **Private** as its `li` has `class="selected"`.

[Updated] Working Fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/prashantkumar_999/rd9zttyn/9/

Comment: `$('.selected').find('a').attr('title')` doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks! you were close.
This worked $('li.selected').find('a').attr('title');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("li.selected>a").attr("title")
```

If you need to be more specific, you can add before the `li`, eg:

```
$(".mainmenu .mainmenulinks li.selected a").attr("title")
```

---

Your fiddle doesn't work as you've

- not included jquery
- not included "." for some classes (but have for others)
- with hasClass, it needs to be in quotes without ".", eg `.hasClass("selected")`
- tried to use `this` outside of a relevant context

---

Prop vs Attr

> **Summary of Preferred Usage**
>
> The .prop() method should be used for boolean attributes/properties and for properties which do not exist in html (such as window.location). All other attributes (ones you can see in the html) can and should continue to be manipulated with the .attr() method.

while `prop` does work and is an easy fall-back incase you're not sure which to use, it should be `attr` for `title`.

Comment: **Thanks!** @freedomn-m This worked for me -> '$('li.selected').find('a').attr('title');'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('li.selected').find('a').attr('title');
```

Updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rd9zttyn/3/ which is working fine